# SSRS SQL 2008 R2 - How to reference the value of other groups?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, bids, ssrs-grouping

I have a matrix setup in the report designer in BIDS. Below is a screenshot:

[image]

All I want to do is use an expression to multiply the value of COL GROUP 1 by COL GROUP 2, for each ROW GROUP as illustrated in red. What would be the best way to achieve this?

EDIT: For clarity, each column group is filtered to only return a single value per adjacent column group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a per row basis, you can use..

```
=ReportItems!ColGroup1Value.Value * ReportItems!ColGroup2Value.Value
```

This assumes that the textbox which contains the value for "ColGroup1Value" is named `ColGroup1Value`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-reportitems-collection-references-report-builder for more information about ReportItems.

Comment: Many thanks, this is the solution i had found in the end. Works well